# Record and dispatch touch event on Android

Tags: android, touch-event

I am trying to record user touch event and replay. Once I was working on a project I was able to emulate a click event using the `dispatchTouchEvent`.

```kotlin
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x,y,0.5f,5f,0,1f,1f,1,0));
Thread.sleep(100)
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x,y,0.5f,5f,0,1f,1f,1,0));
```

So I thought maybe I can listen for touch events and store it into an arraylist, then dispatch it. But it not working.

```kotlin
val events = ArrayList<MotionEvent>()
containerView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    if (isRecordingEnabled) {
        events.add(event)
    }
    return@setOnTouchListener false
}

playBtn.setOnClickListener {
    for (e in events) {
        containerView.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? how can I go about solving this?

Comment: `MotionEvent`s are recycled, so those you're adding to your list are likely invalid when you try to use them at a later time. I've not tested anything, but I would imagine that you'll need to instead store the necessary data from each `MotionEvent` – e.g., the x and y, the action, etc. – and then use `MotionEvent.obtain()` to get a valid, current instance with the list data before calling `dispatchTouchEvent()` with it. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much, The MotionEvent actually recycled after it triggered, instead of storing the MotionEvent directly I only stored the data and when play I recreated the MotionEvent with those data and it worked.